# How to pass pass a bound method of a pointer as an argument?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

If I am given a pointer to an object and I need to pass one of that object's methods as an argument to another function, is that possible?

A very simplified example would look like this:

```
void consumeAFunction(Function func) {
    auto value = func();
    // do some stuff //
}

void main(Object *pointerToObject) {
    consumeAFunction(pointerToObject->someMethod)
}
```

I've tried the following, but I think my understanding of pointers and references is flawed. I'm 3 weeks old in my c++ journey.

​`Object someObject = pointerToObject`​ and `Object someObject = *pointerToObject​`

The specific context of the question is that I have a pointer to an object created by some other library and I need to use `QtConcurrent::run` on that object's methods.

**Additional context**

- `consumeAFunction` is `QtConcurrent::run`
- `Function func` is a method of an `Engine` that simply performs some logic. I am handed a pointer to `Engine` by a third party library.
- I cannot avoid using a pointer to Engine, because it is all I am given to work with.

As much of the specific code as I am allowed to show:

```
// engine is the pointer to someObject:
auto engine = lui::QueryInterop<wise::Engine>(lui::GetLUI()); 
    if (engine) {

        connect(&m_modelsLoadedWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<bool>::finished, this, &ConfigDialog::onNNModelsLoaded);

        // This is the call to consumeAFunction (qtconcurrent::run)
        m_modelsLoadedFuture = QtConcurrent::run(engine->loadPytorchModels);
        m_modelsLoadedWatcher.setFuture(m_modelsLoadedFuture);
```

Comment: What is `Function`?  Is that a template parameter or some sort of `std::function`?

Comment: What is Function? Is is a function pointer, or (something like) `std::function<>`?

Comment: Avoid pointers in modern C++. You rarely need them and they complicate simple things.

Comment: Unrelated: Unless it's in a namespace somewhere, `void main(Object *pointerToObject)` is invalid. There are only two acceptable `main`s and this ain't one of them.

Comment: Some good reading: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: @JesperJuhl That statement might be valid for _owning_ pointers, but we don't know if it's owning here (it could be a reference though).

Comment: Since so many questions for additional details came at the same time I attempted to address them in an edit.

Comment: You might want to try reading the documentation. ["QtConcurrent::run() also accepts pointers to member functions. The first argument must be either a const reference or a pointer to an instance of the class. . . ."](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrentrun.html)

Comment: I'll try to keep that in mind. I was going to suggest looking at std::function until I looked up QtConcurrent::run() to see if if would work with it. That is the other potential approach.

Comment: Side note: *I attempted to address them in an edit.* This is the right way even when requests for more info come in slowly. information is much easier to find and digest if it's inside the question (or answer) body. Plus comments are transient and can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: I don't know how Engine works, but often along with the function pointer you're given the ability to supply a pointer that the function will be called with. The typical strategy is to have a static (or totally free) function that receives the supplied pointer, casts it to the appropriate class, and invokes the member function that you really want called on the pointer. You provide the static function and `this` to the third-party API. API gets a simple C-style function pointer to call and your static function does the rest of the work getting into C++.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a `Qt` question, I highly recommend you get an understanding of `QObject` and `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`.

Because `QObject` is pre-processing via the moc-compiler, a lot of public interfaces, such as properties, methods are exposed in such a way that the object's properties and methods can be inspected at runtime by another plugin and that it doesn't need to know or have access to the header files. This is why something like `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` can work because it has access to the metadata.

Alternatively, if you are using Javascript a lot in QML, you may be interested in passing a Javascript callback function to C++. That function is accessible via `QJSValue`. `QJSValue` usually is used to hold simple types such as strings and numbers. When it holds more complex Javascript types such as arrays, objects, or functions you can use quite a few `QJSValue` methods to unlock their capabilities. In the case of Javascript functions you can verify if it is a Javascript function with `QJSValue.isCallable() == true` and can you can execute it with `QJSValue.call(...)`.